# Query API for login activity events

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

Is possible to query the Microsoft Graph API using an application to collect audit log information for events such as logon/logoff, User creations/deletions, Group membership changes, etc.? I have been looking through the Graph API reference and it does not seem straight forward to me.

Or should we be continuing to use the Azure AD Graph API? We are trying to get data from Office 365 AAD and Azure Government AAD. We are already pulling data from the Office 365 Management API which has an Active Directory feed but not sure that will include everything we are looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Azure AD Audit Log API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/azure_ad_auditlog_overview) provided by Microsoft Graph to access the audit and sign-in logs to track user sign-in activities.  However, this API is currently in Beta so take care with where and how you use it.

In order to work with user accounts, you can use the [User API's](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/user) which provide the capability to create, update, and delete users.

For Group management, take a look at [Working with groups in Microsoft Graph](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/groups-overview).

Also, I would suggest looking through the [Get access tokens to call Microsoft Graph](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_overview) documentation for acquiring access tokens in order to call Microsoft Graph API's and refer to [GitHub repo](https://github.com/microsoftgraph) for various Graph samples.

Comment: This is an excellent answer. Two notes about the User APIs, you cannot delete Admin accounts and there are special restrictions around changing passwords. Both are documented in the above topics but experience (and questions on SO) tells us these notes/nuances are often overlooked. :)